# $.ajax encoding problems

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery

I have the page (encoding 'windows-1251') .php with $.ajax sender:

```
    <div style='float:left;' id='commentRegistration'>                                  
     <input id='addNewCommentUserName' name="name" type="text" size="20" maxlength="30" style="border:1px solid #AAA; width:208px;" value="<?  echo "$_SESSION[login]"; ?>" />
     <textarea id='addNewCommentText' name="text" style="width: 406px; height: 50px; resize: vertical; border:1px solid #AAA;"></textarea>
     <input id='addNewCommentId' name="id" type="hidden" value="<? echo"$myrow[id]"; ?>">     
     <input id='addNewCommentCodeGen' type='text' name='code' maxlength='6' style='border:1px solid #AAA; width:47px;'>   
     <input id='addNewCommentBtn' class='button' style='width:208px; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px;' type='submit' name='submit' value='Добавить комментарий'>   
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){               
                var name = document.getElementById('addNewCommentUserName');
                var text = document.getElementById('addNewCommentText');
                var id = document.getElementById('addNewCommentId');
                var code = document.getElementById('addNewCommentCodeGen');         
                $('#addNewCommentBtn').bind('click',function(){
                    $.ajax({                    
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "comment.php",                 
                        data: { 'name':name.value, 'text':text.value, 'id':id.value, 'code':code.value }            
                    }).done(function( msg ) {

                    });                 
                });
            });
        </script>
```

```
comment.php:

<?  include ("blocks/bd.php"); 
    session_start();    
        header("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) { $name = $_POST['name'];  if ($name == '') { unset($name);} } 
    if (isset($_POST['text'])) { $text = $_POST['text'];  if ($text == '') { unset($text);} }          
    if (isset($_POST['code'])) { $code = $_POST['code'];  if ($code == '') { unset($code);} } 
    if (isset($_POST['id'])) { $id = $_POST['id'];  if ($id == '') { unset($id);} } 
    if (empty($name) or empty($text) or empty($code) or empty($id)) 
    {
        exit ("ErrorEmptyInfo");
    }

    $name = stripslashes($name);
    $name = htmlspecialchars($name);
    $text = stripslashes($text);
    $text = htmlspecialchars($text);    
    $name = trim($name);
    $text = trim($text);

    $mail = "test@mail.ru";
    $subject = "text text text";
    $message = "text text text";
    if (mail($mail, $subject, $message, "Content-type:text/plain; Charset=windows-1251\r\n" ))
    {
        $dateNow = date("Y-m-d");
            iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1251", $text);
            iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1251", $name);
        $addComment = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (post,author,text,date) VALUES ('$id','$name','$text','$dateNow')",$db);    
        echo "SUCCESS";
    }
?>
```

In database $text and $name writes not correctly (encoding problems). I understand that $.ajax send UTF-8 encoding. To change encoding to windows-1251 I use iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1251", $text); not working. How I force to write into my_sql database string with windows-1251 correctly????

Comment: Is there some reason you're using `windows-1251` instead of `utf-8`?

Comment: no, I use it all the time. But now I'm guessing that this encoding well work with my_sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help:

```
$.ajax({                    
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=windows-1251",
    ....
```

Also to force `MySQL` to use `windows-1251` encoding, add this line *Once* after you connect to your database:

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES "cp1251"');
```

**Update:**

You can use the follow instead of `iconv`, that might work:

```
$text = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'Windows-1251');
```

Or:

```
$text = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'Windows-1251', 'UTF-8');
```

**2nd Update**

You might need to comment out these lines. Because your php internal encoding is not `windows-1251`, when you operating some stuff on your strings that might make some problems:

```
/* Temporary commented out, to see if it has any effects
$name = stripslashes($name);
$name = htmlspecialchars($name);
$text = stripslashes($text);
$text = htmlspecialchars($text);    
$name = trim($name);
$text = trim($text);
*/
```

Comment: In this case all variables are empty on comment.php

Comment: Can you try `console.log(text.value);` for example to see what's going there exactly?

Comment: console.log($text); on comment.php 'ReferenceError: $text is not defined'

Comment: @DarienFawkes You should write it there: `$('#addNewCommentBtn').bind('click',function(){ console.log(text.value);` but I realize that might not be a problem. I will update my answer in a few minutes, hope that helps ...

Comment: if I used windows-1251 as (contentType: "application/json; charset=windows-1251") on $.ajax sender all variables on comment.php are empty. On sender I used now (contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8") with it all variables have data. But in my_sql this data writes with encoding error.

Comment: @DarienFawkes I've updated again, I hope this one works at least!

Comment: OK) I it finally work but instead mb_convert_... I used: $text = iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1251", $text); and in comment.php in top write:  header("Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251");